# Next.js router.query getting undefined on refreshing page, but works if you navigate to it from Link component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router, next.js, router

Why is router.query empty when I refresh a page with the correct id in the URL, but when when I navigate towards it through , it works?

say I have **/pages/[user]/index.js**

```
<Link
  href="/[user]/media/[mediaId]"
  as={`/${username}/media/${post.id}`}
>
```

this link takes me to `localhost:3000/testuser/media/some-id`

then in **/pages/[user]/media/[mediaId].js**

```
const MediaPage = () => {
  const [post, setPost] = useState([]);
  const router = useRouter();
  const { mediaId } = router.query;


  useEffect(() => {
    router.prefetch("/");
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!mediaId) return null;
    getPostImage();

    async function getPostImage() {
      try {
        const { data } = await API.graphql({
          query: postById,
          variables: {
            id: mediaId,
          },
        });
        setPost(data.postById.items[0]);
      } catch (err) {
        console.log("error getPostImage", err);
      }
    }
  }, [mediaId]);

  if (user === null) return null;

  return (
    <div>
      <Modal
        className={`${styles.postModal}`}
        isOpen={true}
        onRequestClose={() => router.push(`/${user.username}`)}
        contentLabel="Post modal"
      >
        {* // content ... *}
      </Modal>
    </div>
  );
};

export default MediaPage;
```

When I'm on the media page or `localhost:3000/testuser/media/some-id`, and press refresh, the `mediaId` from router.query is empty.

Comment: Because the param isn’t there there yet. Put it in a useEffect hook and add it to the dependency array.

Answer (score 32):

As mentioned by @Ishan Bassi, using the `isReady` field in `next/router` would indicate when the `query` is fully updated after hydration. Therefore, try something like this:

```
const MediaPage = () => {
  const router = useRouter();

    useEffect(() => {
        if(router.isReady){
            const { media } = router.query;
            if (!mediaId) return null;
            getPostImage();
            ...
         }
    }, [router.isReady]);
   
    ...

}
```

Answer (score 6):

As the `Next.js` documentation says :

> *During prerendering, the router's **query** object will be empty since we do not have query information to provide during this phase. After hydration, Next.js will trigger an update to your application to provide the route parameters in the query object.*

[Automatic static optimization](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/automatic-static-optimization#how-it-works)